# How can I externally inject a new link in an Angular Service Worker webpage and click it without reloading the entire page?

Tags: angular-service-worker

There's an external page that uses Angular Service Worker in which all links open internally without reloading the entire webpage.

But when I try to run a script that injects new links, then clicking those links (both manually and through JS) works but causes to reload the entire page, thus cutting off the script.

The question is - Is there something that can force the webpage not to reload when clicking those links and just treat them like the original links?

The links that can be clicked without reloading the entire page look like
`<a _ngcontent-c32="" href="/something">Something</a>` and use this EventListener:

```
function(e){if(e=e||t.event){var n=this||e.target||t,r=n[C[e.type][f]];if(r)if(1===r.length)y(r[0],n,e);else for(var i=r.slice(),o=0;o<i.length&&(!e||!0!==e[z]);o++)y(i[o],n,e)}}
```

To inject a new link you can just open the console, enter a location and enter `<a href="something_else">test</a>` or if you want even `<a _ngcontent-c32="" href="something">test</a>` or use:

```
var item = document.createElement("a")
document.querySelector('div').appendChild(item) // Tried many other locations too
item.click() // Why does it reload the entire page? Also if clicked manually
```

Comment: Listeners are attached to an element : they don't listen to events on new elements. Attach the listener to your element, and it should work.

Comment: Can you be sure the listener is the deciding factor on whether to reload the entire webpage or not? If so, how can I detect the listener and then attach it to the new element?

Comment: As a sidenote to my answer : I don't know how you can attach the function to the button. It seems your function is an anonymous one and doesn't hold a memory reference : If you manage to find a button with this function as a listener, you could probably get the function and tie it to your own link (be sure to use `apply` or `bind` to get the correct context for the `this` keyword). But that is another issue, sorry I can't be of any help on that, I have never tried to dig in minified+uglified code !

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, all of the existing links ('a' elements) already use this listener. But how do I duplicate their listener?